# Pygame not processing input

Tags: input, pygame

**When Key is pressed on start menu nothing happens**

```
def wait_for_key(self):
    wating = True
    while wating:
        self.clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                wating = False
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pg.K_SPACE:
                wating = False
```

Comment: Not enough information try to put more details what you have tried so far and  what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Luckily in this case there is enough information, as the typo is consistent with the symptom described in the title of this post.

Comment: Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question before asking another question. Usually, the amount of details that you have provided is not sufficient to solve the problem. In future, always provide as many relevant details as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for `event.type == pg.K_SPACE` which is incorrect. What you want to check for is `event.type == pg.KEYDOWN`. Once you know it's a key down event, then you can check for `event.key == pg.K_SPACE`.